# Button calls itself numerous times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game and I am trying to create a buff slot system with 3 buttons and a buff shop with 7 buttons. What I want to do is every time a buff slot button is clicked, it will open the buff shop panel and when the user clicks on one of the 7 buffs in the panel, the buff button's image will transfer into the buff slot button.

I have implemented just about everything so when I click the first buff slot and select a buff, the buff slot's image will change to the buff selected. But when I click on the second buff slot and select another buff, it will replace the image on both buttons. And then the third one will do the same for all 3 buttons. Almost like recursively calling itself when I click on other buttons. How can I avoid the buttons from changing the other buttons' images? I am fairly new to Unity/C# and I would appreciate any suggestion I can get.

EDIT: Sorry! I completely forgot to even post the code. That's my mistake! Here's what I have so far:

```
    //This is where I initialize the buttons under Start()
    buffSlot_1.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_1.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_1));

    buffSlot_2.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_2.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_2));

    buffSlot_3.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_3.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_3));
```

This is what the method does:

```
void addBuff(Button button) {

    buffPanel.GetComponent<GameObject>();
    buffPanel.SetActive(true);

    damageBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    damageBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Gain a damage boost!");
        dmgBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        damageBoostButton.interactable = false;
        button.image.overrideSprite = damageBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    defenseBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    defenseBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Gain a defense boost!");
        defBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        defenseBoostButton.interactable = false;
        button.image.overrideSprite = defenseBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    critBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    critBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Crit Boost");
        critBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        critBoostButton.interactable = false;
        button.image.overrideSprite = critBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    hasteBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    hasteBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Haste Boost");
        hasteBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        hasteBoostButton.interactable = false;
        button.image.overrideSprite = hasteBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    iceSpikeButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    iceSpikeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Increase Ice Spike");
        iceSpikeBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        iceSpikeButton.interactable = false;
        button.image.overrideSprite = iceSpikeButton.image.sprite;
    });

    iceWallButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    iceWallButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Increase Ice Wall");
        iceWallBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        iceWallButton.interactable = false;
        button.image.overrideSprite = iceWallButton.image.sprite;
    });

    healthRegenButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    healthRegenButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("HPRegen Boost");
        hpRegenBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = false;
        healthRegenButton.interactable = false;
       // button.image.overrideSprite = healthRegenButton.image.sprite;
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: no code, no one knows

Comment: So you're asking us where your code is calling a given method, but you refuse to show us your code. I'm putting $10 on line 123, let me know if I win the pool.

Comment: Please read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, specifically this sentence: "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: You're going to need to post examples of the actual source code behind your buttons before anyone can give you a meaningful response.

Comment: Why would you think a vague description of your code would be easier to debug than **your actual code**?

Comment: Sorry guys! I edited the main post. I wasn't particularly "refusing to show code", I am currently working and got tied up with coding other scripts that I completely forgot to put my code in.

Comment: So I guess you just have to wait until some 3k+ rep person wanders back to this post and votes to reopen it. That is unfortunate as it's already been many hours since you edited the post and added in the code.

Comment: Every time you click a buff slot, it adds new listeners to your 7 buff-shop buttons in addition to the ones that are already there. Click BuffSlot1 => Adds BuffSlot1 to `damageBoostButton` button listener, now click BuffSlot2 => Adds BuffSlot2 to `damageBoostButton` button listener => Now `damageBoostButton` has listeners for both BuffSlot1 and BuffSlot2, so when you click on `damageBoostButton` each listener runs and each is told to assign `damageBoostButton.image.sprite;` to their button, so BuffSlot1 and BuffSlot2 each get the same image.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Quantic. I notice that what you mentioned could certainly be the issue. But due to my lack of knowledge and understanding of C# and Unity's functionalities, I'm unsure of how to change this aspect. I am trying different things but they end up returning the same results. :( I guess I will have to wait for someone with a higher rep to re-open it. I did not mean to mess up my first post haha.

Comment: Clicking a buff slot should not add a listener to buff shop buttons, after clicking 3 buttons you have 3 listeners that all run. You should add the buff-shop button listeners only once at start, then you need to modify your code such that each listener does what you need. This might work: clicking buffslot1 could set a global variable, "activeButton = buffSlot_1;", then the listener for all your shop buttons will do `activeButton.image.overrideSprite = {this button's sprite}`. Only add that listener once at start.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that yet. I will give it a try but I may need help implementing the function. I am looking at guides as well but none are doing what I want them to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do not code in Unity, so consider some of this "pseudo-code". The general idea should be workable, however.

The changes are: The buff-shop listeners are now added only once in Start(). These same listeners have references to `button` replaced with `ActiveButton`. Clicking a buff-slot button now only assigns the active button then opens the buff-shop. The buff-shop's buttons now only have 1 listener each because new listeners are never added after Start() any more, and each listener will use `ActiveButton` to assign images to only the active button instead of to every listener that was added.

Note: before this change, if you clicked a buff-slot 100 times you would end up with 100 listeners on each buff-shop because every time you click the button it would add a new listener. This is basically a memory leak in addition to the other problems it has. You should only add listeners once, or remove them when you are done with them. The code here only adds them once.

```
// Some globally visible area of your code
public Button ActiveButton { get; set; }

//This is where I initialize the buttons under Start()
void Start()
{
    buffSlot_1.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_1.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_1));

    buffSlot_2.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_2.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_2));

    buffSlot_3.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_3.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_3));

    // Initialize buff slot listeners. These are added only once in Start()
    damageBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    damageBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Gain a damage boost!");
        dmgBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        damageBoostButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = damageBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    defenseBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    defenseBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Gain a defense boost!");
        defBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        defenseBoostButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = defenseBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    critBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    critBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Crit Boost");
        critBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        critBoostButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = critBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    hasteBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    hasteBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Haste Boost");
        hasteBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        hasteBoostButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = hasteBoostButton.image.sprite;
    });

    iceSpikeButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    iceSpikeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Increase Ice Spike");
        iceSpikeBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        iceSpikeButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = iceSpikeButton.image.sprite;
    });

    iceWallButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    iceWallButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("Increase Ice Wall");
        iceWallBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        iceWallButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = iceWallButton.image.sprite;
    });

    healthRegenButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    healthRegenButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        Debug.Log("HPRegen Boost");
        hpRegenBool = true;
        buffPanel.SetActive(false);
        ActiveButton.interactable = false;
        healthRegenButton.interactable = false;
        ActiveButton.image.overrideSprite = healthRegenButton.image.sprite;
    });
}

// Clicking a buff-slot button opens the buff-shop, 
// and assigns the global ActiveButton variable to the button that was clicked.
void addBuff(Button button) {

    buffPanel.GetComponent<GameObject>();
    buffPanel.SetActive(true);

    ActiveButton = button;
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. I did try that just now and it did not entirely work. But thanks for your help! I will keep playing around with this syntax and see what I can get from it. :)